# Understanding Example #3 of FileOpen() from the documentation page

Tags: autohotkey

With the `FileAppend` command, its as simple as calling a compiled `.ahk` file from a terminal window, to get back an output from the script. For example:

```
;@Ahk2Exe-ConsoleApp
FileAppend, Hello World! , *
```

I want to start using `FileOpen()` but it seems more complicated, regardless I want to use it, from here on.

I have been experimenting with example #3 of the [`FileOpen()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/FileOpen.htm#ExStreams) page in the docs, which is:

```
; Open a console window for this demonstration:
DllCall("AllocConsole")
; Open the application's stdin/stdout streams in newline-translated mode.
stdin  := FileOpen("*", "r `n")  ; Requires [v1.1.17+]
stdout := FileOpen("*", "w `n")
; For older versions:
;   stdin  := FileOpen(DllCall("GetStdHandle", "int", -10, "ptr"), "h `n")
;   stdout := FileOpen(DllCall("GetStdHandle", "int", -11, "ptr"), "h `n")
stdout.Write("Enter your query.`n\> ")
stdout.Read(0) ; Flush the write buffer.
query := RTrim(stdin.ReadLine(), "`n")
stdout.WriteLine("Your query was '" query "'. Have a nice day.")
stdout.Read(0) ; Flush the write buffer.
Sleep 5000
```

It seems just reducing the example down to:

```
;@Ahk2Exe-ConsoleApp
stdout := FileOpen("*", "w `n")
stdout.Write("Hello World")
```

and calling the compiled executable outputs `Hello World` at the calling terminal window.

So I have to wonder what is the first line `DllCall("AllocConsole")` for?
Further more, the line `stdout.Read(0) ; Flush the write buffer` what is being meant by `Flush the write buffer`? Is there a particular reason why these lines are present in the example.

I am worried that I will run into issues later on down the line if I ignore them now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!